# sorting a list of object based on the property date sudo object values

Tags: java, android

I have a class named SomeClass which has two properties: SomeDateObject  and a list of SomeClass2. I wants to sort  a given list of SomeClass   objects on the basis of SomeDateObject. by means wants to sort

```
 public List<SomeClass  > someClassList
```

How to achieve the sorting based on SomeDateObject

The structure of SomeClass   is given as below :

```
 public class SomeClass  {


        public SomeDateObject date;

        public List<SomeClass2> some2;

        public SomeClass  () {
        }
    }
```

The structure of SomeDateObject is given as below

```
public class SomeDateObject {

        public int day;
        public int month;
        public int year;
}
```

What can be the best way to sort the list of SomeClass   objects based on SomeDateObjects. as we can use Comparator and comparables but SomeDateObject  is not a straight forward date but is having date details. Rather than using a straight Comparator can we go for guava-libraries.

Comment: using `Comparator` and `Collections`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Collections.sort` with a `Comparator` like this,

```
Collections.sort(SomeClassList, new Comparator<T>() { 
\\ T is a type parameter, you need to pass type argument here

@Override
public int compare(T lhs, T rhs) {
        return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
    }
});
```